# How to discard data from the first sliding window in Dataflow?

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

I'd like to recognize and discard incomplete windows (independent of sliding) at the start of pipeline execution.  For example:

If I'm counting the number of events hourly and I start at :55 past the hour, then I should expect ~1/12th the value in the first window and then a smooth ramp-up to the "correct" averages.

Answer (score 3):

Since data could be arbitrarily late in a user-defined way, the time you start the pipeline up and the windows that are guaranteed to be missing data might be only loosely connected.

You'll need some out-of-band way of indicating which windows they are. If I were implementing such a thing, I would consider a few approaches, in this order I think:

- Discarding outliers based on not enough data points. Seems that it would be robust to lots of data issues, if your data set can tolerate it (a statistician might disagree)
- Discarding outliers based on data points not distributed in the window (ditto)
- Discarding outliers based on some characteristic of the result instead of the input (statisticians will be even more likely to say don't do this, since you are already averaging)
- Using a custom pipeline option to indicate a minimum start/end time for interesting windows.

One reason to choose more robust approaches than just "start time" is in the case of down time of your data producer or any intermediate system, etc. (even with delivery guarantees, the watermark may have moved on and made all that data droppable).